# How to get all the Form elements, with values, in a popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one functionality to get the print of current page. So to prepare the content, I am showing everything on one popup up first then later a print popup and then print command.

Trying to do the same with below code.

```
$('#button').on('click',function() { 
    var popup = window.open("","mypopup","width=500,height=300");
     var html = $("#form").html();
    $(popup.document.body).html(html);
    popup.print();
});
```

[image: Image of output]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaikratsingh/0v9mdow6/1/)

Tried with clone() method as well but not working.

So the issue is, I am not getting the element's values in my popup.

Thanks

Comment: I thought `clone()` would copy the values as well. You can always copy one by one.

Comment: it would help if you post a working fiddle of what you already have

Comment: a modal window would be better suited to this task, any reason you're not using one?

Comment: @cr0ss Added jsfiddle link. Sorry for the delayed reply. I had left for the day yesterday.

Comment: @stefan, Modal window of jquery?? Actually the main purpose is just to get the print of current page. Nothign else. I am not doing anything extra on that popup window.

Answer (score 3):

HI Use simple jquery line for each input field.

You can add a value attribute for your input fields.

I have changed your script a bit. Please refer it.

```
$('#button').on('click',function() { 
    var popup = window.open("","mypopup","width=500,height=300");
// I am setting the value attribute in the html . Do this for all fields
// with similar input fields you can have a jQuery('input').each(); loop
    $('#name').attr('value',$('#name').val());

    var html = $("#form").html();
    $(popup.document.body).html(html);
    popup.print();
});
```

Comment: Yes, its working. Thanks for the answer.  But I have around 50+ fields. So this does not seems to be a good approach in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Manually send the data from form through ajax call and store it in a local websql (browser)storage which can be retrived in the print preview dialog box